# Laravel 4 - Form data not being submitted into db

Tags: forms, laravel-4

I'm a bit stumped as to why the form data is not being submitted into the db from the code below. I'm a bit new to Laravel 4, and I surmising I am missing a call somewhere in the code. When I click submit I'm re-routed but the entry isn't added to the database. Help would be appreciated in pointing out what I am missing. Thank you so much.

**EntriesController.php**

```
<?php

class EntriesController extends BaseController {

#Handles "GET /" request
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('home')->with('entries', Entry::all());
}   

#Handles "POST /" request
public function postIndex()
{
    $entry = array(
        'username' => Input::get('frmName'),
        'email'    => Input::get('frmEmail'),
        'comment'  => Input::get('frmComment')
    );

// save the guestbook entry to the database
Entry::create($entry);

return Redirect::to('/');
}
}

?>
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 4 Guestbook</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach ($entries as $entry)
        <p>{{ $entry->comment }}</p>
        <p>Posted on {{ $entry->created_at->format('M jS, Y') }} by 
           <a href="mailto:{{ $entry->email }}">{{ $entry->username}}</a>
        </p><hr>
    @endforeach

    <form action="/" method="post">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmEmail" value="" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td><input textarea name="frmComment" row="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Entry.php**

```
<?php
```

class Entry extends Eloquent {

```
   /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'entries';

}

?>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('/', 'EntriesController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**EntriesController.php**

```
<?php

class EntriesController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {

        $entries = Entry::all();

        //->with('entries', Entry::all());
        //in Laravel 4.1, variable pass with 'With' will be process via Session.
        // changed 'with' to 'compact'

        return View::make('home', compact('entries'));
    }   


    public function store()
    {
        $entry = array(
            'username' => Input::get('frmName'),
            'email'    => Input::get('frmEmail'),
            'comment'  => Input::get('frmComment')
        );

        // save the guestbook entry to the database
        Entry::create($entry);

        // Name route `index`
        // resourceful controller create 7 routes for you
        // http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

        return Redirect::route('index');
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('/', 'EntriesController');
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 4 Guestbook</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach ($entries as $entry)
        <p>{{ $entry->comment }}</p>
        <p>Posted on {{ $entry->created_at->format('M jS, Y') }} by 
           <a href="mailto:{{ $entry->email }}">{{ $entry->username}}</a>
        </p><hr>
    @endforeach

    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'store')) }}
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmEmail" value="" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td><input textarea name="frmComment" row="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion with switching out the form tags, and although it doesn't error out or redirect me, it doesn't add the new form values to the page. It just submits and doesn't display the new information just submitted.

Comment: Hi, do you want to use resource controller instead of restfull controller? why? read: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Comment: If you want to use resource controller, let me know.

Comment: Anam, I am in the process of learning Laravel 4 and this is just what the example tutorial suggested. I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working and learning from the process. But yes, if using a resource controller can RESOLVE the problem then I would very much like to learn how to use this.

Comment: I will write the answer soon. in the mean time you can learn about the Laravel resource controller and restful routing. https://laracasts.com/lessons/understanding-rest

Comment: Any issue let me know.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out that link while I await your possible solution. Cheers mate!

Comment: I went ahead and changed up the code again per your suggestion and came up with the "Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
username" error. I've added a protected $fillable array('username', 'email', 'comment'); in User.php but the error still persists after I hit submit.

Comment: The original tutorial I was working off of: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-introduction/

Comment: Fixed, I put the $fillable variable in the wrong filer, user.php instead of entry.php. thanks for all the help Anam and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Form Action is pointed to the wrong place.  The '/' path is your `getIndex()` route.  I believe it should be:

```
  <form action="postIndex" method="post">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried that, and got the following error - Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.